# Git reset not working the way I want it to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I never ran `rake assets:precompile` before and never needed to. I think when I push to heroku such is done automatically.

After committing to git I was playing around and ran `rake assets:precompile` for the first time. This kind of seems to have cluttered my public folder. `git status` indeed showed all these new (untracked) files.

So I wanted to revert back to the last git commit and undo this. I ran `git log` and determined the id of the last commit. I then ran `git reset --hard 4a9aa***f76`. It confirmed `HEAD is now at 4a9aa72 ...`. However, `git status` still shows all these new files. How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git reset will not remove untracked files. you can either delete them manually or run `git clean -f`

Answer (score 0):

Or just add the files you want to delete and stash them.

```
git add .
git stash
git stash clear
```